# How it is possible to run two separate chrony instances (on a same pc): one client and one server

Tags: linux, ntp, rhel8, chrony

[image: NTP configuration]

All ntp servers and clients are implemented using chrony on RHEL 8.2.

NTP client [200.100.1.3] has no access to [NTP server 200.100.1.1].

NTP client [200.100.1.2] has to get time information from NTP server [200.100.1.1]. There must be a server in 200.100.1.2 to give time information to NTP client 200.100.1.3 .

I know how to configure NTP server and NTP client using chronyd. Either server or client but not both on a same pc.

How to run two chronyd in one machine/pc, one acting as a client to get time information from 200.100.1.1, another acting as a server to give time information (captured from NTP server [200.100.1.1],updated as system time) to NTP client on 200.100.1.3

How it is possible to run two separate chrony services (on a same pc) to take configuration from two separate chrony.conf files.

Chrony.conf in /etc/ for client

```
server 200.100.1.1 iburst
local stratum 10
allow 200.100.0.0/16
# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift

# Allow the system clock to be stepped in the first three updates
# if its offset is larger than 1 second.
makestep 1 -1

maxdistance 1000000

# Enable kernel synchronization of the real-time clock (RTC).
rtcsync

# Specify file containing keys for NTP authentication.
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys

# Get TAI-UTC offset and leap seconds from the system tz database.
leapsectz right/UTC

# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony
```

Chrony.conf in /etc/ for server

```
server 200.100.1.2 port 123 iburst

# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
allow 200.100.0.0/16
local stratum 10
# Allow the system clock to be stepped in the first three updates
# if its offset is larger than 1 second.
makestep 1.0 3

# Enable kernel synchronization of the real-time clock (RTC).
rtcsync

# Specify file containing keys for NTP authentication.
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys

# Get TAI-UTC offset and leap seconds from the system tz database.
leapsectz right/UTC

# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony
```

cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952460/how-it-is-possible-to-run-two-separate-chrony-instances-on-a-same-pc-one-clie

Comment: AFAIK each ntp client can act by default as server.

Comment: The `man chrony.conf` has a server section. Have you read it? It's also fairly [trivial to find good material using google](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/chrony-time-services-linux), so I somehow doubt the amount of research that went into this.

Comment: @RomeoNinov What you told was true. Nowhere this fact is clearly mentioned